# What is the section between the package name and the class activity called

Tags: java, android

Can we say that this is the outer scope of the application? since to my knowledge there is no other capability than importing libraries in that area i wouldn't consider it as the outer scope but i could be wrong. What do we call this space? i am writing an essay describing my college project and i want to be precise about it.

```
package tk.gregory.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has little to do with Android and a lot to do with Java. I am not aware of a particular term to refer to that portion of the file. It is just the `import` statements. The term "outer scope" does not really have meaning in this context, so I would not use that term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people call it the *imports section*.

`import` in Java is a mechanism to name the types you use with unqualified names, e.g. `AppCompatActivity` in place of fully qualified `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`.